# d3 (v4) zoom using transitions doesn't seem to work

Tags: d3.js

I am using the d3 zoom behaviour and attempting to use a transition for both a `translateTo` and a `scaleTo` at the same time. If I make the calls to zoom without a transition everything works fine. If I use a transition for just one of the transforms it also works, but if I attempt to use a transition for both it fails (it appears to only apply the first transform). I have a JSFiddle with several combinations here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PeteThompson/z2amv1dv/)

Here's the code that isn't working as I expect

```
svg.transition()
  .duration(750)
  .call(zoom.scaleTo, 2)
  .call(zoom.translateTo, 50, 50)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
svg.transition()
  .duration(750)
  .call(zoom.scaleTo, 2)
  .transition() <--- this is missing.
  .call(zoom.translateTo, 50, 50)
```

First zoom then translate.

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tztemkuu/)

**EDIT**

Performing zoom and translate both  @ same time you need to tween.

```
function twizzle(selection, duration) {
  d3.select(selection).transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .tween("attr:transform", function() {
        //interpolate from start to end state
        var i = d3.interpolateString("scale(1)translate(0,0)", "scale(2)translate(50,50)");
        return function(t) { 
                    selection.attr("transform", i(t)); 
                };
      });
}
```

Now call the function like this:

```
d3.select('body')
  .append('button')
  .text('transition both - scale first')
  .on('click', function() {
    //on click call the function created above
    group.call(twizzle, 750) <-- perform the scale and translate on the group not on the SVG.
  })
```

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/1u8rv3x7/)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to have it to do both transforms at the same time (i.e. smoothly pan and zoom all in one go)?

Comment: OK, please check my **edit** i have added the code to perform scale + translate.

Comment: Thanks - that works in isolation, but doesn't play nice with the d3 zoom. E.g. if you pan or zoom using the mouse before clicking the button those steps are lost and the transition happens from 0,0. That said, I'll take this and have a play next week to see if I can use a transition with a tween to call the zoom methods directly rather than trying to use the more helpful zoomTo and translateTo methods.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. You can call the zoom.transform method on a transition and it will handle the transition for you. The awkward thing is that you lose the nice convenience of the translateTo method and have to calculate the translate part of the transform yourself. I've updated my fiddle with something that seems to work and behaves appropriately if you use the mouse to pan and zoom. Here's the important piece of JavaScript:
    svg.transition()
   .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.transform,d3.zoomIdentity.translate(100, 150).scale(2))

can you update your answer?